# XML: The process cannot access the file

Tags: c#, xml

I have 5 lists and want to save them to XML. My code works for 4 of them but I absolutely have no idea but it does not want save the fifth. I use overloaded method SaveXML for every list. There is problem only with saving rooms. I always got exception: The process cannot access the file Rooms.xml...

```
public class Database
{
        List<Student> dtbStudents = new List<Student>();            
        List<Teacher> dtbTeachers = new List<Teacher>();
        List<StudyProgramme> dtbPrograms = new List<StudyProgramme>();
        List<Subject> dtbSubjects = new List<Subject>();
        List<Room> dtbRooms = new List<Room>();            

        public Database()
        {
            LoadXML();
        }

        public void SaveXML()
        {
           SaveXML(dtbStudents);
           SaveXML(dtbTeachers);
           SaveXML(dtbPrograms);
           SaveXML(dtbSubjects);
           SaveXML(dtbRooms);
        }
        public void SaveXML(List<Teacher> list)
        {
             XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(list.GetType());
             using (TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter(@"Teachers.xml"))
             {
                  serializer.Serialize(writer, list);
             }
        }
        public void SaveXML(List<StudyProgramme> list)
        {
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(list.GetType());
            using (TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter(@"StudyProgrammes.xml"))
            {
            serializer.Serialize(writer, list);
            }
         }
         public void SaveXML(List<Student> list)
         {
             XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(list.GetType());
             using (TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter(@"Students.xml"))
             {
                serializer.Serialize(writer, list);
             }
         }
         public void SaveXML(List<Subject> list)
         {
             XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(list.GetType());
             using (TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter(@"Subjects.xml"))
             {
                 serializer.Serialize(writer, list);
             }
         }
         public void SaveXML(List<Room> list)
         {
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(list.GetType());
            using (TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter(@"Rooms.xml"))
            {
            serializer.Serialize(writer, list);
            }       
         }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Database dtb = new Database();

        dtb.SaveXML();               
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Can be problem with Loading data from xmls or what? I can post that function.
Thanks for help!

Here my load function:

```
public void LoadXML()
    {
        XmlReader Reader = XmlReader.Create(@"Students.xml");
        XmlSerializer deserializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Student>));
        dtbStudents = (List<Student>)deserializer.Deserialize(Reader);

        Reader = XmlReader.Create(@"Teachers.xml");
        deserializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Teacher>));
        dtbTeachers = (List<Teacher>)deserializer.Deserialize(Reader);

        Reader = XmlReader.Create(@"StudyProgrammes.xml");
        deserializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<StudyProgramme>));
        dtbPrograms = (List<StudyProgramme>)deserializer.Deserialize(Reader);

        Reader = XmlReader.Create(@"Rooms.xml");
        deserializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Room>));
        dtbRooms = (List<Room>)deserializer.Deserialize(Reader);

        Reader = XmlReader.Create(@"Subjects.xml");
        deserializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Subject>));
        dtbSubjects = (List<Subject>)deserializer.Deserialize(Reader);

        Reader.Close();
    }
```

Comment: i only see 3 `SaveXML` that take a list.

Comment: there are three dots.. i can post them, but they are same only with different parameter

Comment: a [mcve] would be great

Comment: What happens when you debug it yourself? And where does it pop the error?

Comment: right here: using (TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter(@"Rooms.xml"))

Comment: What is the complete error message?  I'm willing to be another process has a lock on the file and that's why you can't access it to save.

Comment: An unhandled exception of type 'System.IO.IOException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: The process cannot access the file 'C:\Users\Marko\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\MichalOstranskyPortal\MichalOstranskyPortal\bin\Debug\Rooms.xml' because it is being used by another process.

Comment: Do you have it open in an editor?

Comment: Side note: you could actually save you the trouble of overloading the `SaveXml` methods. The bodies differ only in the file name. You could write only one generic method and give it as parameters `List<T> list` and `string filename`

Comment: No. Everything is closed.

Comment: Yeah, I know that my solution with overloading is not so good and there is possible to create one method with List<T> but I really dont know how to do correctly yet...still beginner with generic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `LoadXML()`, you only close the *last* reader instance:

```
    XmlReader Reader = XmlReader.Create(@"Students.xml");
    // Snip code for reading
    Reader = XmlReader.Create(@"Teachers.xml");
    // Snip code for reading
    Reader = XmlReader.Create(@"StudyProgrammes.xml");
    // Snip code for reading
    Reader = XmlReader.Create(@"Rooms.xml");
    // Snip code for reading

    Reader = XmlReader.Create(@"Subjects.xml");
    // Snip code for reading
    // Here the last instance is closed -- but the other four were
    // never closed.
    Reader.Close();
```

Thus the first four `XmlReader` instances are abandoned when the value of the reference variable `Reader` is changed, and so will get closed *eventually* when garbage collected and finalized.  If one of the files is still open later when you try to write back because the finalizer thread hasn't closed the file yet, you will get the exception you are seeing.

Instead, you should dispose of each instance as soon as you are done with it:

```
    using (var reader = XmlReader.Create(@"Students.xml"))
    {
        XmlSerializer deserializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Student>));
        dtbStudents = (List<Student>)deserializer.Deserialize(reader);
    }

    // Similarly for the others.
```